# Prove by contraditcion that $a\mid b$ then $ac\mid bc$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, divisibility

> Prove by contradiction if $a\mid b$ then $ac\mid bc $ for $a,b,c\in\Bbb Z$

I am having considerable difficulty with this problem. Could someone give me a step-by-step solution? Even though the problem seems simple, I cannot solve it. I am new to discrete maths: I only know direct proof and contraposition (I am trying to work on contradiction). All I know is that $a\mid b$ if for some other number $c$, we have $b = a\times c$.

Comment: What are your thoughts about the problem? Can you give a proof that does not use contradiction? Do you know the meaning of the statement $a|b$? Give us something to work with.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! I can relate to the fact that you are stuck on a math problem; it happens to me all the time and it can be frustrating, I know. However, regardless of your confusion, you will get more useful answers on this and future questions if you *provide more context.* A good first step would be to post what you have tried so far into the body of the post. Whether you have but a few words to say, or several paragraphs, you will get a better answer this way :)

Comment: With my new edit, can you help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with not ac | bc.  We wish to show not a | b.
Assume a|b.  Easily prove ac | bc, a contradiction
from the starting premise.  Thus not a|b.

It is pointless to prove this by contradiction
as a direct proof is easy and simple.

Comment: Why is a contradiction ?

Comment: @HenriqueN.Mendes.  Proof by contradiction is a red herring because a direct proof in much easier.  Certainly you can prove a|b implies ac|bc directly.

Answer (score 0):

Assume $c>0 $, suppose on contrary $\forall k\in \mathbb Z$ $$ac\neq k bc.$$ Let $ac>kbc$. Then $a>kb$. similarly for $ac<kbc$. consider the other case also $c<0$. In each case we get $a $ not divides $b$.